# SQL Server trigger partially updating from Linq To Sql code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a table (`Equip`, which is the inserted) that has a trigger that updates another table (`asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_JobAssetMaint`) with data.  If I manually update the data in `Equip` through SSMS, the trigger updates the `Maxtemp` and `RunHrs` columns in `asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_JobAssetMaint` properly.

If I edit `Equip` through Linq To Sql code in C#, `Equip` is updated but `asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_JobAssetMaint` is only partially updated from the trigger.

i.e.  The data in `Equip` is correct, but 2 of the columns, `Maxtemp` and `Runtime`, don't get carried over to the `asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_JobAssetMaint` columns, `Maxtemp` and `RunHrs`

Here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Eis_JobAssetMaint_trigger_new] 
ON [dbo].[Equip]
For INSERT, UPDATE
AS 



BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @runhrsDiff float,
            @jobID int,
            @partno varchar(20),
            @assetno varchar(36),
            @maxtemp float,
            @runtime float,
            @assetID int


    SELECT  @jobID = (Select JobID from inserted),
            @partno = (Select Part_No from inserted),
            @assetno = (Select Asset_No from inserted),
            @maxtemp = (Select MaxTemp from inserted),
            @runtime = (Select RunTime from inserted)

    SELECT @runhrsDiff = t2.runtime - t1.Runhrs FROM asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_JobAssetMaint AS t1  INNER JOIN INSERTED AS t2 
    ON t1.Part_No = t2.part_no AND t1.Asset_No = t2.asset_no AND t1.jobid = t2.jobid


            IF Exists (Select t1.jobid,t1.Asset_No,t1.Part_No from asset_tracker.dbo.Eis_jobassetmaint as t1
                        inner join Inserted  T2 on T1.Jobid = T2.jobid and T1.Part_no = T2.Part_no and T1.Asset_No = T2.Asset_no)

                Begin 

                    UPDATE t10 SET t10.RunHrs = t10.Runhrs+@runhrsDiff
                    , t10.maxt = CASE WHEN t12.maxtemp > t10.maxt then t12.maxtemp ELSE t10.maxt END 
                    from asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_repairlog_maint as t10 
                    INNER JOIN asset_tracker.dbo.eis_repairlog  as t11 ON t10.repair_number = t11.repair_number AND t11.repair_status IN (1,4,6,7) AND t11.repair_type IN (13,14,15)
                    INNER JOIN INSERTED AS t12 ON t12.part_no = t11.part_number AND t12.asset_no = t11.asset_number


                    Update T1  set T1.RunHrs = T2.Runtime , T1.MaxTemp = T2.MaxTemp
                    From Inserted as T2 inner join asset_tracker.dbo.Eis_JobAssetMaint as T1 
                    on T2.Jobid = T1.jobid and T2.Part_no = T1.Part_no and T2.Asset_No = T1.Asset_no
                End
            Else

                BEGIN TRY
                    ----------------- new line
                    UPDATE t10 SET t10.RunHrs = t10.Runhrs + t12.runtime
                    , t10.maxt = CASE WHEN t12.maxtemp > t10.maxt then t12.maxtemp ELSE t10.maxt END 
                            from asset_tracker.dbo.EIS_repairlog_maint as t10 
                            INNER JOIN asset_tracker.dbo.eis_repairlog  as t11 ON t10.repair_number = t11.repair_number AND t11.repair_status IN (1,4,6,7)
                            INNER JOIN INSERTED AS t12 ON t12.part_no = t11.part_number AND t12.asset_no = t11.asset_number




                    IF EXISTS (SELECT t1.Assetname, t1.Part_No from asset_tracker.dbo.AssetPositions as t1
                                inner join Inserted  as t2 on T1.Part_no = T2.Part_no and T1.Assetname = T2.asset_no)
                        IF NOT Exists (Select t1.jobid,t1.Asset_No,t1.Part_No from asset_tracker.dbo.Eis_jobassetmaint as t1
                                inner join Inserted  T2 on T1.Jobid = T2.jobid and T1.Part_no = T2.Part_no and T1.Asset_No = T2.Asset_no)
                            BEGIN
                                PRINT ('Attempting to insert new record into JobAssetMaint')
                                Insert into asset_tracker.dbo.Eis_JobAssetMaint 
                                    (    Jobid
                                        ,Part_no
                                        ,Asset_no
                                        ,MaxTemp
                                        ,MaxTempIgnore
                                        ,RunHrs
                                        ,RunHrsIgnore
                                        ,jobcnt
                                        ,JobCntIgnore
                                        ,MaxShock
                                        ,MaxShockIgnore
                                        ,LastUpdated
                                    )
                                    VALUES ( @jobID,
                                            @partno,
                                            @assetno,
                                            @maxtemp,
                                            0,
                                            @runtime,
                                            0,
                                            1,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            getdate()
                                            )

                                    --From inserted
                            END
                END Try

            BEGIN CATCH

                --Declare @jobid int 
                select @jobid = jobid from inserted 
                        RAISERROR   (N'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EIS_JobAssetMaint 2_AssetPositions". The conflict occurred in database "asset_tracker", table "dbo.AssetPositions".The current JOBID is:%d ',10, 1,@jobid);
            END CATCH



END
```

Hopefully this is not too confusing.  If so, let me know.

Comment: Ok in the first place your trigger is bad even if you thought it worked. It needs to be rewrtitten from scratch as you NEVER set values form inserted to a scalar variable. Inserted can contain multiple rows and you need to make sure that is hwo the trigger is written. To do anythign else is irresponsible.

Comment: we understand that. Before we didn't have variables.  This was something we tried for troubleshooting.

Comment: I imagine the problem is probably related to the above. I'd suggest changing the assignment of the relevant variables to "SELECT TOP 1 MaxTemp FROM Inserted"

Comment: John, your idea is looking promising.  I talked to my DBA and he made the changes per what you said.  And it seems to be working so far.  We are not in complete confirmation yet.  But so far so good.

Comment: John, post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 0):

Here is my hint on troubshooting complex triggers. Take out the create trigger part and change inserted or deleted (or both) to temp tables called #inserted or #deleted. Before running the reaming scriptcreate the #inserted table and populate it with test data that fits the possible things you need to test. Now you can run the rest of the script a bit at a time and see the values of things that you are trying to find with test code. Once you are done, remove the test code, change#inserted back to inserted and put inteh create or alter trigger parts.